# What should I look for in a cyclo cross bike

Tags: cyclocross, hybrid-bike

This will be my first cyclo cross bike and I am already using the same techniques with my mtb.
My question is what should I look for in it. Since the country I live in does not have any official brand manufacturing cyclo cross bikes, I have to look for the nearest replacement.
So what should I look for, like rigid frame, type of brakes gears, anything such

My use is based on high speed sprints and short length moderate offroad  use

A few more things carbon fibre frames are not easily available so I prefer other materials, I live in a rainy place(recently its been more rainy for past 2 years, likely to continue in future)

Comment: This question is too broad.   CX are rigid.  Disc or cantilever brakes.   Shimano or SRAM.  1x or 2x.    Carbon or aluminum frame.  Without knowing how you want to use the bike cannot help you with what to look for.

Comment: @Blam, I updated the question hope it helps

Comment: Since your area is rainy, sounds like you will be riding though mud a lot, I would recommend disk breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to go on.  Disc brakes for wet.  2x set up if you are going to use is on the road.  You probably want clincher wheels.  Aluminum frame.

Not technically a CX but a bike like this http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/city/fitness/crossrip/

Comment: ...or specialized tricross (http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bikes/archive/2014/tricross) since I assume Specialized is widely available all over the world.

Comment: The bike seems quiet relevant, let me search it this Month and see what happens, also let me see other people opinion.

Comment: There are lots of bikes.  That is just an example.

Comment: @Blam, I found nearly the same bike as in the trekbike link that you suggested, thanks  for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specifically looking to race cyclocross then gravel bikes might be more suited to your general off road / on road riding.
Disc brakes should probably be prioritised, then everything else will be fine whatever is specified on the bike from manufacturer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Without meaning this personally, saying that a buyer should prioritize disc brakes on a gravel bike was not that informative even in 2015. If all gravel bikes weren't on discs by then, they are now.

Comment: Without taking it personally, the question is badly worded and many used cyclocross bikes will still have centre pull rim brakes. Is the user buying new? The real issue here is probably they don't know the difference between xc and gravel bikes.